# Change background color of adapter item inside firestore query

Tags: android, firebase, listview, google-cloud-firestore, android-adapter

I have a made an adapter that shows a `ListView` with items. The information about the items is read from `Firestore` database and inserted inside the ListView by using Firestore queries and setting this data to the item in the adapter.

One of the parameters in my Firestore data is `ReturnedDate`. If the field exists, I had like the backgroung of the item in the list to be in different color.

Basically what im trying to do is:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

*some lines of code to set other views*


CollectionReference Ref = db.collection("Users").document(auth.getUid()).collection( "MyBorrowed" );
Query query = Ref.whereEqualTo("ID", item.getId());
query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

                if (document.get("ReturnedDate") == null) {

                } else {
convertView.setBackgroundColor(MyBorroweAdapter.this.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed));

                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Problem is that im getting an error of `"convertView is accessed from within inner class, needs to be final"`

However I cant make it final in an adapter..

Is there any way to overcome this problem?

**SOLUTION:**

I managed to solve this by declaring at the beginning of the adapter:

```
public View layout;
```

Then inside my `getView`:

```
viewHolder.layout = convertedView;
```

Eventually when setting the background:

```
viewHolder.item_layout.setBackgroundColor(MyBorrowedAdapter.this.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed));
```

Thank you

Comment: you should instead create a final variable in `getView()` like, `final View anotherConvertView = convertView;`